# Unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required

Tags: rust

I'm trying to return an error Result with a `&'static str`.

```
impl Worker {
    fn get_task_by_name(&self, name: String) -> Result<Box<Task>, &'static str> {
        Err("Task not found!");
    }
}
```

It outputs the following error:

```
src/lib.rs:84:5: 84:8 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
src/lib.rs:84     Err("Task not found!");
                  ^~~
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a spurious semicolon after the `Err(...)`.  You're telling the compiler to throw away the value you construct and return `()` instead.  Of course, it doesn't get as far as telling you the return type is wrong: it's more immediately confused by the fact that you've constructed a `Result<T, E>::Err(E)` without telling it what `T` is.